# What is the idiomatic way to compare two lists for equality?

Tags: list, erlang, elixir

I have two lists I need to check whether their elements are equal (not shallow check, for elements I might rely on `Kernel.==/2`.)

Currently, I have:

```
[l1 -- l2] ++ [l2 -- l1] == []
```

It looks a bit overcomplicated and not quite idiomatic to me. Am I missing something? Is there a better way to compare two lists for equality?

Comment: What do you mean by "not shallow check"? Can you give an example where `l1 == l2` doesn't work?

Comment: @Dogbert `~w|a b|a == ~w|b a|a`. By “not shallow” I mean I do not recursively compare the content of elements.

Comment: Like `MapSet.new(l1) |> MapSet.equal?(MapSet.new(l2))`?

Comment: @Dogbert nope; equal elements are permitted:  `~w|a a b|a` is not equal to `~w|a b|a`.

Comment: Ah, then `Enum.sort(l1) == Enum.sort(l2)`? It should run faster than your solution (`n log n` vs `n ^ 2`).

Comment: @Dogbert, yes, thanks,  I thought about `Enum.sort` but it’s still looks too much repetitive. It’s still better, indeed.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The shortest way I can think of is to sort the lists and compare them:

```
Enum.sort(l1) == Enum.sort(l2)
```

This will run in `O(n log n)` time instead of `O(n ^ 2)` for your `Kernel.--/2` based solution.

We can't use a plain Set data structure here since the list can contain duplicates and their counts must be kept track of. We can use a Map which counts the frequency of each element and then to compare them:

```
iex(1)> l1 = ~w|a a b|a
[:a, :a, :b]
iex(2)> l2 = ~w|a b|a
[:a, :b]
iex(3)> m1 = l1 |> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn x, acc -> Map.update(acc, x, 1, & &1 + 1) end)
%{a: 2, b: 1}
iex(4)> m2 = l2 |> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn x, acc -> Map.update(acc, x, 1, & &1 + 1) end)
%{a: 1, b: 1}
iex(5)> m1 == m2
false
iex(6)> l2 = ~w|a b a|a
[:a, :b, :a]
iex(7)> m2 = l2 |> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn x, acc -> Map.update(acc, x, 1, & &1 + 1) end)
%{a: 2, b: 1}
iex(8)> m1 == m2
true
```

This is also `O(n log n)` so you may want to benchmark the two solutions with the kind of data you'll have to see which performs better.

Answer (score 2):

Dogbert's solution is apt, but it is still in Orcish.

In Erlang this would be:

```
lists:sort(List1) == lists:sort(List2)
```

A deep comparison looks very nearly the same, but of course must traverse the structures within each list.

One factor to consider is that *very often the ordering of a list **is** its meaning*. Strings are a good example, so are player ranks, start positions, game hotkey locations, and last-used-longest-kept cache lists. So *do* keep in mind the meaning of the comparison: "Do these two lists *contain* the same number and type of things?" is not the same as "Are these two lists *semantically identical*?"

Consider comparing anagrams:

```
lists:sort("AT ERR GET VICE") == lists:sort("IT ERR ETC GAVE")
```

That works fine as an anagram comparison, but not at all as a semantic one.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I understand the consequences of comparison without order. I just needed to compare maps keys, so the order did not matter in my particular case. In Elixir there is also [`Enum.group_by/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#group_by/3) that could be of any use (or could not :). I just wanted to ensure myself `sort` + `==` is a way to go.

Comment: @mudasobwa Indeed! I just wanted to expand on the subject a little more as the question (taken at face value) is pretty broad in how it is phrased, but applies to a rather specific situation. Map key comparisons and (especially) set comparisons (among other operations) are super useful in a huge number of situations as well.

Comment: Why is Dogbert's solution in Orcish? 
Or what is it meant by that; is it (Orcish)[https://wowpedia.fandom.com/wiki/Orcish_(language)]?

Comment: It is a joke I assume. Dogbert's solution is in Elixir while zwq9 gives the Erlang equivalent.  Erlang is the language that underpins Elixir so there can be a gentle rivalry between practitioners.

Comment: He says that Dogbert's solution is relevant ("apt"), but it is "in Orcish". My understanding is that Orc (character) are "aggressive" or "ugly" since the author prefers Erlang to Elixir (my assumption). It's still very valid solution - one can call Erlang code in Elixir programs.